# Reading variables for a set of Checkbuttons in TKinter

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have a set of Checkbuttons on root.frame1 and I want to use the selected ones in a subframe of root to make an optionmenu. The approach I have taken is:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
frame1 = Tk.Frame(root)
variables = dict()
s = {'WZ':'1','ZB':'2','RS':'3','CC':'4','CL':'5'}
for k,v in s.iteritems():
     variables[k]= Tk.IntVar()
     cb = Tk.Checkbutton(frame1, text=v,onvalue=v, offvalue=0, variable=variables[k], anchor=W)
     cb.pack(side='top',fill='x')

frame1.pack()
```

and then when I select some of the checkbuttons, the values in the variables dictionary are still 0:

```
for k,v in variables.iteritems():
      print k,' ',v.get()
```

which prints out:

```
'WZ' 0
'ZB' 0
....
```

I tried to use a list of tuples instead of a dictionary i.e. variables =[('WZ',),...] but still the values don't change. 
Do you know what is wrong with my code? Please let me know. 
Thanks
Ali

Comment: I'd change some parts, but your code works for me. Have you tried replacing `Tk.IntVar()` with `Tk.IntVar(frame1)`?

Comment: The code also works for me on a Mac with python 2.7. Can you show a complete working program, so we can see how you're printing the values out? My guess is, you're somehow printing them before the mainloop runs.

Comment: That's right. Being a newbie to Tkinter, I was printing the variables before running the mainloop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me. However, it would help to work with runnable code. Does this work for you?

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.variables = {}
        s = {'WZ':1,'ZB':2,'RS':3,'CC':4,'CL':5}
        for k, v in s.iteritems():
             self.variables[k] = tk.IntVar()
             cb = tk.Checkbutton(
                 frame, text=k, onvalue=v, offvalue=0,
                 variable=self.variables[k],
                 command=self.oncheck(k),
                 anchor='w')
             cb.pack(side='top',fill='x')
        frame.pack()
    def oncheck(self, key):
        def _oncheck():
            print('{l} => {v}'.format(l=key, v=self.variables[key].get()))
        return _oncheck

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. I should've run the mainloop(). The only difference is in my s dictionary the values are strings and when I define the onvalue to be a string, the checkbuttons appear disabled.